# How to remove white space on website from SVG symbol at botton of index.html

Tags: html, css, svg, symbols, visibility

On youtube I learned how to place my SVG code inside a  elements at the bottom of my index.html and whenever I want to use the SVG then I would use the  tags. Doing this makes sure that  my code remains clean and it worked.

Now I am finished with my project but under my footer, there is this big white space. When using chrome inspect, I can see that the white space is used for the bottom SVG's. Even when styling the SVG to visibility: hidden; , it is still showing the white space.

How should I approach this problem so that the bottom SVG's are in my index.html but not on my live server page?

In the image: the brown part is my footer and the white space underneath is what I am talking about.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rwnJ.jpg)

In the first part you can see how I use the  elements

```
<article class="service-blocks service-block1">
                    <div class="square">
                        <svg class="cog-icon" width="80"><use href="#cog-icon"></use></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="triangle"></div>
                    <div class="service-text">
                        <h3><strong>Mobile first</strong></h3>
                        <p>Start with mobile and work your way up with media queries.</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
```

Here you see the SVG saved at the bottom

```
<!-- SVG 3 column top ---------------------------------------------->
<div class="svgs">
<svg style="visibility: hidden;">
    <symbol id="cog-icon" 
            class="icons" 
            aria-hidden="true" 
            focusable="false" 
            data-prefix="fas" 
            data-icon="cog" 
            role="img" 
            viewBox="0 0 512 512" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path   fill="white" 
                d="M487.4 315.7l-42.6-24.6c4.3-23.2 
                4.3-47 0-70.2l42.6-24.6c4.9-2.8 
                7.1-8.6 5.5-14-11.1-35.6-30-67.8-54.7-94.6-3.8-4.1-10-5.1-14.8-2.3L380.8 
                110c-17.9-15.4-38.5-27.3-60.8-35.1V25.8c0-5.6-3.9-10.5-9.4-11.7-36.7-8.2-74.3-7.8-109.2 0-5.5 1.2-9.4 
                6.1-9.4 11.7V75c-22.2 7.9-42.8 19.8-60.8 35.1L88.7 
                85.5c-4.9-2.8-11-1.9-14.8 2.3-24.7 26.7-43.6 58.9-54.7 
                94.6-1.7 5.4.6 11.2 5.5 14L67.3 221c-4.3 23.2-4.3 47 
                0 70.2l-42.6 24.6c-4.9 2.8-7.1 8.6-5.5 14 11.1 35.6 
                30 67.8 54.7 94.6 3.8 4.1 10 5.1 14.8 2.3l42.6-24.6c17.9 
                15.4 38.5 27.3 60.8 35.1v49.2c0 5.6 3.9 10.5 9.4 11.7 36.7 
                8.2 74.3 7.8 109.2 0 5.5-1.2 9.4-6.1 9.4-11.7v-49.2c22.2-7.9 
                42.8-19.8 60.8-35.1l42.6 24.6c4.9 2.8 11 1.9 14.8-2.3 24.7-26.7 
                43.6-58.9 54.7-94.6 1.5-5.5-.7-11.3-5.6-14.1zM256 336c-44.1 
                0-80-35.9-80-80s35.9-80 80-80 80 35.9 80 80-35.9 80-80 80z">
        </path>
    </symbol>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

```
I tried removing the bottom SVG's and the white space disappeared. But then I lost the purpose of this technique to not clutter my code with SVG-code.

I tried using an direct style on the SVG --> visiblility: hidden; but the space was still showing

I put the SVG's in a div and give the div a visibility: hidden; style but I had the same issue as above.
```

Comment: There is incorrect syntax, you need a closing tag for the `<div class="svgs">` , just after `</svg>`

Comment: Your question is not very cleat to me. However visibility:hidden hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout. Try using position:absolute and width="0" height="0" for the <defs> svg element

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you for your answer. You fixed it. The other answers didn't work because they omitted position absolute.

I thought with the screenshot I added + the entire code that my explanation would be clear. Sorry if it wasn't. I am only learning writing code since mid-September. I never did anything before that regarding this. It is not always easy to explain by writing something I don't understand what exactly is causing something.
 
Thank you so much for your answer! I wish I know how to upvote it. But I am also a noob for using this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the bottom SVG invisible you can set the height and width to 0. The CSS property `visibility` will hide content, but it will still take up the space on the page.

Also, to remove the white space around the icon in the top set both width and height.

```html
<article class="service-blocks service-block1">
  <div class="square">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="cog-icon" width="80" height="80">
      <use href="#cog-icon" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="service-text">
    <h3><strong>Mobile first</strong></h3>
    <p>Start with mobile and work your way up with media queries.</p>
  </div>
</article>

<!-- SVG 3 column top ---------------------------------------------->
<svg width="0" height="0" style="display:none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="cog-icon" 
            class="icons" 
            aria-hidden="true" 
            focusable="false" 
            data-prefix="fas" 
            data-icon="cog" 
            role="img" 
            viewBox="0 0 512 512" >
    <path fill="orange" d="M 487.4 315.7 l -42.6 -24.6 c 4.3 -23.2 4.3 -47 0 -70.2 l 42.6 -24.6 c 4.9 -2.8 7.1 -8.6 5.5 -14 c -11.1 -35.6 -30 -67.8 -54.7 -94.6 c -3.8 -4.1 -10 -5.1 -14.8 -2.3 L 380.8 110 c -17.9 -15.4 -38.5 -27.3 -60.8 -35.1 V 25.8 c 0 -5.6 -3.9 -10.5 -9.4 -11.7 c -36.7 -8.2 -74.3 -7.8 -109.2 0 c -5.5 1.2 -9.4 6.1 -9.4 11.7 V 75 c -22.2 7.9 -42.8 19.8 -60.8 35.1 L 88.7 85.5 c -4.9 -2.8 -11 -1.9 -14.8 2.3 c -24.7 26.7 -43.6 58.9 -54.7 94.6 c -1.7 5.4 0.6 11.2 5.5 14 L 67.3 221 c -4.3 23.2 -4.3 47 0 70.2 l -42.6 24.6 c -4.9 2.8 -7.1 8.6 -5.5 14 c 11.1 35.6 30 67.8 54.7 94.6 c 3.8 4.1 10 5.1 14.8 2.3 l 42.6 -24.6 c 17.9 15.4 38.5 27.3 60.8 35.1 v 49.2 c 0 5.6 3.9 10.5 9.4 11.7 c 36.7 8.2 74.3 7.8 109.2 0 c 5.5 -1.2 9.4 -6.1 9.4 -11.7 v -49.2 c 22.2 -7.9 42.8 -19.8 60.8 -35.1 l 42.6 24.6 c 4.9 2.8 11 1.9 14.8 -2.3 c 24.7 -26.7 43.6 -58.9 54.7 -94.6 c 1.5 -5.5 -0.7 -11.3 -5.6 -14.1 z M 256 336 c -44.1 0 -80 -35.9 -80 -80 s 35.9 -80 80 -80 s 80 35.9 80 80 s -35.9 80 -80 80 z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: So setting the width and height to 0 in the index.html between the <symbol></symbol> tags, I will after have to set a new width and height in the CSS whenever I need to use it?

Comment: The w/h of the two SVGs has nothing to do with each other. Any SVG has a default w/h. In your case the SVG with the <symbol> should be invisible, therefore 0 w/h. The SVG with <use> also has default w/h. Therefore you need to specify w/h for that as well.

Comment: Thank you! display: none + w/h: 0, also did the trick! Another comment said to use position: absolute together with w/h: 0; both solutions work! Thank you again